# How to wait until toolbar is present in skribbl.io | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to program a skribbl.io hack. Skribblio is a website where you draw something and people have to guess what you have drawn. I need the bot to wait until the drawing toolbar is present and interactable before trying to draw anything. I am trying to use this code to do this:

```
Class Drawing:
  #some other code


  def response(self):
    try:
      self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".containerToolbar[style]")))
    finally:
      return 'found'

D = Drawing()

while True:
  if D.response() == 'found':
    print('got good response')
    break
```

however, found is returned as soon as I enter the pre game lobby. The game hasn't even started and this has already been returned. Its's probably worth mentioning that the drawing tooblbar looks like this when it is invisible:

```
<div class="containerToolbar" style="display: none;">
```

and like this when it is visible:

```
<div class="containerToolbar" style>
```

If someone can do some research themselves by making a private game and joining it on another tab that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`WebElement Desired_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your xpath")); WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBe Clickable/visible/enable(Desired_element )); Desired_element.click;` you need to try similar thing in python